# How to allow users to draw only within a specified area in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, android-view-invalidate

In my Android Project I have a drawView which user can draw.

And it draw a body shape by using x Coordinates, y Coordinates and `Bitmap.setPixel`.

A example of the body shape: https://ibb.co/KDNXhhX.

What I want to do is, that user can draw anywhere, but after the pen moved up(which means `ACTION_UP`), all the draw outside of the body would disapper. In other word, it only keep the draw inside the body.

I have checked the documentation about `invalidate()` from View, but it only invalidate a Rect or a drawable. How can I do this?